# Sorting a custom array based on String Array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter

I have to `sort` an `array` of `Custom class` '`SongItem`' based on another `array` which is my `String array` with multiple types (have to apply `OR` validation).

Suppose my `Custom array` is :

```
class SongItem: NSObject {

    var songId: String?
    var title: String?
    var artistName: String?
    var isrc: String?

    var genreArray = [String]()
}

<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
<SongItem: 0x1c03097e0>
```

I have another `String array` that has three values:

```
genreStringArray = ["Music","Alternative","Blues"]
```

Now I have to `filter` my `Custom array` based on another `String array`.

Here is my code:

```
for i in 0..<genreStringArray.count {

     let genre  = genreStringArray[i]
     self.customArray = self.customArray.filter({ $0.genreArray.contains(genre) })
}
```

As I am using `for loop` here so `filtering` is working fine in AND manner, but I have to filter this with OR manner. I mean this should be like :

```
self.datasource = self.datasource.filter { $0.genreArray.contains(genre1) || $0.genreArray.contains(genre2) || $0.genreArray.contains(genre3)}
```

Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here, what is `genre1`, `genre2` and `genre3`? maybe you should add some sample data (the print of th Custom array is not helpful) and expected output

Comment: I have given example with genre1, genre2 and genre3 as different types of genreStringArray.

Comment: That makes no sense. Is `genreArray` the same as `genreStringArray`? And is `datasource` the same as `custom array`?

Comment: Currently what happening if there are two item in my custom array, then after applying filter I am getting empty custom array.

Comment: Can you share you SongItem Model

Comment: genreArray is one of the property in my Entity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do.

```
customArray.filter({ !Set($0.genreArray).intersection(Set(genreStringArray)).isEmpty })
```

No need for an extra `for` loop. Just check if the `genreStringArray` and the `genreArray` of your object have common elements. If it does, then it is filtered in.

---

**Tip:** You should probably use better naming for your variables so that it is less confusing and simple. Something like this maybe?

```
class Song {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var artist: String?
    var isrc: String? // I don't know what this is!

    var genres = [String]()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesha for your response. Can you pls check my updated question, genreArray is one of my property of my entity class.

Comment: @user2786 yes i am aware of that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rakesha, this works.. isrc is basically ISRC Id used in Apple Music/iTunes.